# Geoserver WMST Date Format

Tags: geoserver, sql, sql-server, time, wmts

There is table in SQL-Server 2008 R2.  In this table I have date column with date format like this `2006-09-08 14:39:41.000`. Now I make a view from this table on GeoServer side and do nothing with the date field. And make WMST layer.

When I go into Layer Preview I do not see any features. I then take source table and publish it on GeoServer, but GeoServer does not see date column.

In the [GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/time.html) docs I see that in WMST I have to use the ISO-8601 time format.

How can I convert date format in view on GeoServer?

**UPDATE**

I make some tests.

I take Shapefile with date field (i.e. 2002-08-20) put it into SQL-Server using `ogr2ogr`. SQL-Server says that my date field is date data type. GeoServer says it too, and in Layer Preview I see my features and after adding in address line `TIME=2002-08-21` parameter I can see features with other dates.

Then I added a `datetime` field in my table and put into dates like `2002-08-20 14.00.00.000`. GeoServer says that it's `Timeswap` datatype. In Layer Preview I DON'T GET any features added and   `TIME=2002-08-21T14.00.00.0Z` also doesn't not help.

When I click on map I get error that `can't convert varchar into datetime`.

Comment: Not sure but you need to convert few things. Please check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509977/convert-varchar-into-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: @Sunil: So you mean that i gonna have dates in seconds format like this `2312009`?

Comment: Yes. you need to convert and then check the result